# How to clean WordPress URL and remove get parameter name?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm using wordpress for a site,

this url before **example.com/?uin=XXXXX** i want url like this **example.com/XXXXX**
Is there any way to do this.

My .htaccess file looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /adotcreation/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /adotcreation/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: is the certificates a different directory? otherwise WP will assume /certificates as a page slug and /XXXXX as child page of /certificates

Comment: Just to add... this isn't something you do in `.htaccess` - you need to do this in WordPress itself since you need to change how WordPress constructs the links to your pages. Maybe the WordPress SE would be a better fit for this question? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/